# Getting New Random Numbers For Guessing Game In Java

Tags: java, class, random

I am building a game for Java and I've gotten down to one of the last parts.  There are still other things to fix which are easy fixes. Although there is one problem I can't figure out, which is that after every time I run the game I can't get new random numbers to show up.

For instance, if nobody guesses the number that is made at random by the computer from numbers (1-20) than the game repeats itself.  You are playing 2 computers during this and their numbers are also made up at random (again 1-20 values).

Here is some of the code for the Player class I made

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Player {
    private double currentGuess = 0;
    private String firstName;
    private boolean isCorrect;
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public Player() {
}

public double autoGuess()   {
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    double number = randomNumber.nextInt(20) + 1;

    return number;
}
```

Here is my GuessGame class, which is where the action actually happens.  I cannot figure out why when I call for the autoGuess method (from the player class) I cannot get new random numbers to show up after each game which resulted in nobody guessing the right number. Same goes for randomly generating the number to be guessed (WINNING_NUMBER), it still stays the same after every new game.  Here is some of the code of my GuessGame class.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessGame {
    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player player2 = new Player();
    Player player3 = new Player();

    double player2Guess = player2.autoGuess();
    double player3Guess = player3.autoGuess();
    int numberOfTries = 0;

public double generateWinningNumber()   {
    Random randomGenerate = new Random();
    double randomNumber = randomGenerate.nextInt(20) + 1;

    return randomNumber;
}

private final double WINNING_NUMBER = generateWinningNumber();

public void startGame() {
    System.out.println("VM: Welcome we are going to play a number guessing game. I'm (the JVM)\n"
            + "going to randomly pick a number between 0 and 20. You and the 2 other\n"
            + "computer-generated players are going to try to guess that number. The game\n"
            + "will end when at least one of the players correctly guesses the number.\n");

    System.out.println(WINNING_NUMBER);

    System.out.print("What is your name?  ");
        String player1Name = player1.readName();

    while (player1.isCorrect() == false)    
        {

        System.out.print(player1Name + ", enter your guess:  ");
            player1.readGuess();
            player2.autoGuess();
            player3.autoGuess();

            numberOfTries++;

            if (player1.getCurrentGuess() == WINNING_NUMBER || player2Guess == WINNING_NUMBER || player3Guess == WINNING_NUMBER)
            {
                player1.setCorrect(true);
                displayGuesses();
                determineWinner();
            }

            else
            {
                displayGuesses();
                displayHints();
                System.out.println("No one guessed the number.\nPlayers will need to guess again.\n");
                System.out.println("The winning number was: " + WINNING_NUMBER);
                generateWinningNumber();
            }
        }   
}


public void displayGuesses()    {
    System.out.print("Player 2's guess is: " + player2Guess + "\n");
    System.out.print("Player 3's guess is: " + player3Guess + "\n\n");
}
```

There is more to this and obviously more to fix, but I'm trying to just get this issue out of the way.  I have my driver class starting this game and also know I need to round my numbers to Ints so there isn't a decimal place.  Also, all the hint method is referring to is just if statements that tell you if you are hot, warm, or cold.  That runs perfectly fine.  Just needing some help with figuring out how to get a new random number after every new unsuccessful game from my while statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `generateWinningNumber()` method returns a double, it does not actually change any values itself. Also, because `WINNING_NUMBER` is a constant, even if you did want to change it, you wouldn't be able to. You should definitely not make `WINNING_NUMBER` final, and either modify `generateWinningNumber()` so that it modifies your global variable itself, or leave it as-is and use its return value to assign to your non-constant `winningNumber` global.

Comment: ...and create the Random() object outside the loop.

Comment: To add to what Mike said, your autoGuess() also returns a double and does not change any values. instead of returning the variable number as a double, the function should just set the currentGuess to the variable number and return void.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Isn't it already, though? The Random objects are being created in separate methods, so they're never reused.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! Sorry if the formatting isn't per-say great or anything; I'm trying to get better at it.

Comment: As a side note, change all those double variables to int, and make the functions return int as well.

Comment: @Mike, that's my point. The Random() object *should* be reused, not recreated, otherwise you don't get a good random distribution.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Oh, of course, that makes perfect sense, I wasn't thinking straight it seems